# Dynamic Placeholders no longer working in EE after upgrade

Tags: experience-editor, placeholders, dynamic-placeholder

We recently upgraded to Sitecore 10.1.3, but our site is still primarily using webforms layouts. This issue is with the webforms dynamic placeholders.

Our regular placeholders work fine in EE - they show the empty look when they contain no components, and the "Add Here" button appears

```
<sc:placeholder runat="server" key="Ph5050LeftColumn"></sc:placeholder>
```

Our dynamic placeholders, which use custom code, work when published (the components in the dynamic placeholders display as expected), but the editing controls are not available in EE.

```
<div class="right-container" style="background-color:<%= BackgroundColor%>" data-placeholder="<%= PlaceholderKeyRight %>">
    <PageEditor:DynamicKeyPlaceholder runat="server" ID="Ph30RightColumn" Key="Ph30RightColumn" />
    </div>
<div class="test-container">
    <sc:placeholder runat="server" key="Ph5050LeftColumn"></sc:placeholder>
</div>
```

[image]

I can see in the inspector that the necessary Javascript is not being generated for the dynamic placeholder - the `div class="scenabledchrome scemptyplaceholder"` - but don't know why. The code block looks exactly the same, except for the keys being different.

Here is the code for the dynamic placeholders:

```
public class DynamicKeyPlaceholder : WebControl, IExpandable
{
    protected string _key = Placeholder.DefaultPlaceholderKey;
    protected string _dynamicKey = null;
    protected Placeholder _placeholder;

    public Placeholder InnerPlaceholder
    {
        get { return _placeholder; }
    }

    public string Key
    {
        get { return _key; }
        set { _key = value.ToLower(); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the dynamic key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// a)  Get stack of placeholders
    /// b)  Get current, placeholder at top of stack, (last processed)
    /// c)  Get a list of renderings that are in this placeholder
    /// d)  Get the last rendering in the list
    /// e)  This rendering’s unique id is appended to the placeholder.key to become the dynamic key.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <value>
    /// The dynamic key.
    /// </value>
    public string DynamicKey
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dynamicKey != null)
            {
                return _dynamicKey;
            }
            _dynamicKey = _key;
            //find the last placeholder processed, will help us find our parent
            Stack<Placeholder> stack = Switcher<Placeholder, PlaceholderSwitcher>.GetStack(false);
            if (stack.Count == 0)
            {
                //not used within a placeholder apparently. dynamic key is actually not necessary in this case.
                return _dynamicKey;
            }
            Placeholder current = stack.Peek();
            //find the rendering reference we are contained in
            var renderings = Sitecore.Context.Page.Renderings.Where(rendering => (rendering.Placeholder == current.ContextKey || rendering.Placeholder == current.Key) && rendering.AddedToPage).ToList();
            if (renderings.Any())
            {
                //last one added to page defines our parent
                var rendering = renderings.Last();
                //use rendering reference unique ID to uniquely and permanently identify the placeholder
                _dynamicKey = _key + rendering.UniqueId;
            }
            return _dynamicKey;
        }
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Tracer.Debug("DynamicKeyPlaceholder: Adding dynamic placeholder with Key " + DynamicKey);
        _placeholder = new Placeholder();
        _placeholder.Key = this.DynamicKey;
        this.Controls.Add(_placeholder);
        _placeholder.Expand();
    }

    protected override void DoRender(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        base.RenderChildren(output);
    }

    #region IExpandable Members

    public void Expand()
    {
        this.EnsureChildControls();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I assume this is related to Sitecore javascript files changing between 8.2 and 10.

**UPDATE** I found that if I create a placeholder in Sitecore with the dynamically generated key, e.g. ph30leftcolumn{94E08B2F-54A4-4950-9099-91071AEC68A1}, the controls show up. This seems like an issue with the Javascript (or maybe a Sitecore pipeline) not associated the dynamic keys with the key in Sitecore (ph30leftcolumn)

Comment: You upgraded from 8.2?

Comment: Yes, that is what I said

Comment: In Sitecore 10, dynamic placeholders were added OOTB. I wonder if some of the newly added pipelines around that are overriding the key or adding elements to it?

Comment: You didn't say that you upgraded from 8.2

Comment: I would suggest you to create a fresh dynamic placeholder in SC10 and see if that works. If it does then you can compare migrated ones with new one to find out the problem.

Comment: RichardSeal I know they were added OOTB with MVC but with webforms?

Comment: VikrantPunwatkar do you have guidance on how to do that? I have been unable to find documentation on how to create dynamic placeholders in webforms for Sitecore 10